# Unable to renew Personal Access Token (PAT) from web portal on TFS2018

Tags: tfs

I was able to renew /change PAT expires in drop box with 30 days to 1 year from TFS web portal.

But now unable to renew a token created at *11/5/2018*. It caused our multiple builds failed.

How to renew this kind of token, did I miss any setting?

Besides, is it able to **auto-refresh PAT tokens** so CI jobs can run without having to manually refresh tokens ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working as designed. **One PAT can only be used for a maximum of one year.**

> If the PAT created at the beginning is 90 day, when it expires, you
>   can choose to change to 180 days or 1 year. But if you start in 1 year
>   and expire soon after one year, you can only add another new token.

We appreciate that idea about having a function to auto-refresh PAT tokens.

However,  we don't have an API support for this. And trying to automate PAT generation or extending expiry of a PAT also falls outside of security best practices.

You'll have to manually refresh the PAT each year. We do **send you an expiry notification 7 days before the expiry** of a PAT.

Comment: you could also want to look at the SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken that one is generated by the build agent and is always up to date.

Comment: Thanks for confirmed. We end up manually recreating a new different. Everything backs to normal.